# Game on the unit segment, $n$ players (points).

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, game-theory

**The $n$ player *1-dimensional* unit game**

The $n\ge 2$ players take turns placing their own point on the unit segment $[0,1]$. (Hence, *1-dimensional*.)

The closest distance they can place their point to someone elses placed point is some small $\varepsilon\gt 0$.

A player owns the part of the segment closest to their own point. The goal is to own the largest part of the segment. That is, say $a,b$ are closest points to your own point $x$. Then:

- If your point ends up between two points $x\in(a,b)$ then your score is $s_x=\frac12(b-a)$.
- If your point ends up in $x\in[0,a)$, then your score is $s_x=\frac12 (x+a)$.
- Symmetrically, if your point $x\in(b,1]$, then your score is $s_x=1-\frac12 (x+b)$.

> Which player(s) have the winning strategy? (Have highest chance of highest score, then maximize that score.)

WLOG (Symmetry) first player plays in $x_1\in[0,\frac12]$.

I've observed so far that the optimal play (and winniners) should be:

- $(n=2)-$ Is a win for the $1$*st* player. Player plays $x_1=\frac12$.
- $(n=3)-$ Is a win for either  $1$*st* or $2$*nd* player (coin flip). Players play $x_1=\frac14+\frac12\varepsilon$ and $x_2=1-x_1$, then $x_3\in(x_1,x_2)$ uniformly randomly (we assume if a player is presented with equally good choices, he picks uniformly randomly), which results in $0.5$ chance (a coin flip) for the one of the $x_1,x_2$ to win (have highest score).

More details are below. Do correct me if I missed anything about $(n=3)$ there.

> Can we find strategies and winners for $n\ge 4$ ?

---

**$2$-player case is a win for $1$*st* player**

For $n=2$, it is not hard to see that the first player has a winning strategy by playing $x_1=\frac12$.

The most the second player can score then is by playing $x_2=\frac12-\varepsilon$.

This nets them $s_2=\frac12 (\frac12-\varepsilon+\frac12)=\frac12-\frac12\varepsilon$ score, while the first player now has $s_1=\frac12+\frac12\varepsilon$.

[image]

---

**$3$-player case is a win for either $1$*st* or $2$*nd* player with $0.5$ probability**

For $n=3$, this strategy does not work for the first player anymore.

The third player would play $x_3=\frac12+\varepsilon$. (Mirror the second player.)

The second and third player now share the win by both having $\frac12-\frac12\varepsilon$ score.

The first player is now in $x_1\in(x_2,x_3)$ and their score is reduced to a minimal $\varepsilon$.

[image]

So WLOG if in $n=3$ the winning strategy exists for the first player, they will play in $x_1\in[0,\frac12)$.

Now the question is, what would be the optimal response of the second player to this?

The first player plays $x_1=\frac12-\delta$. Assuming $\delta$ is small enough, the second player can play $x_2=\frac12+\delta+\varepsilon$ to win the game. Notice that this play makes $[0,x_1)$ more favorable for the third player, than the $(x_2,1]$, meaning the third player would leech off the first player.

That is, by small $\delta$ we are assuming that the score $s_3$ of $x_3$ if they would play in $x_3\in(x_1,x_2)$ is smaller than if they would play optimally in $[0,x_1)$. In other words we are assuming $\delta \lt \frac14-\frac12\varepsilon$ here:

$$s_3((x_1,x_2))\lt s_3([0,x_1)) \iff \delta+\frac12\varepsilon\lt \frac12-\delta-\frac12\varepsilon \iff \delta \lt \frac14 -\frac12 \varepsilon$$

This forces $x_3$ to play in $[0,x_1)$, namely $x_3=\frac12-\delta-\varepsilon\implies s_3=\frac12-\delta-\frac12\varepsilon$.

The score of the second player will be $s_2=\frac12-\frac12\varepsilon$, and the first player will have $s_1=\delta+\varepsilon$.

We have $s_1\lt s_3 \lt s_2$. This now gives a winning strategy for second player if $x_1\in(\frac14+\frac12\varepsilon,\frac12]$.

[image]

So WLOG if in $n=3$ the winning strategy exists for the first player, they will play in $x_1\in[0,\frac14+\frac12\varepsilon]$.

If $x_1=\frac14+\frac12\varepsilon$ and $x_2=(1-x_1)+\varepsilon$ still, then $x_3$ would play uniformly randomly in $x_1\in(x_1,x_2)$ for $s_3=\frac14+\varepsilon$. This will result in $x_1$ winning with slightly larger probability than $0.5$ (depending on the size of $\varepsilon$), and other times $x_2$ will win. Can $x_2$ now change its strategy to improve its odds?

- If it increases the $\varepsilon$ increment, is has worse odds. (Depending on the size of the $\varepsilon$.)
- If it removes it, both players $x_1,x_2$ have exactly $0.5$ chance of winning. ($x_2$ mirrors $x_1$)
- If it decreases the $\varepsilon$ increment, is now always loses because $x_3\in(x_2,1]$ is forced.

That is, for $x_1=\frac14+\frac12\varepsilon$ it seems the optimal strategy for second player is $x_2=1-x_1$, to mirror it. This forces the $x_3$ to play uniformly randomly in $(x_1,x_2)$, giving both $x_1,x_2$ equal chances of winning (probability $0.5$).

The question now remains, can first player do better than $0.5$ if he picks $x\in[0,\frac14+\frac12\varepsilon)$ ?

It seems that if $x_1$ plays in this interval (is closer to $0$), this allows the $x_2$ to decrease the mentioned increment (come closer to the $\frac12$) without making $(x_2,1]$ more valuable than the $(x_1,x_2)$ for the $x_3$ to play in. Hence $x_2$ has higher probability than $0.5$ of winning now.

From all of these cases for $x_1$, it follows that the optimal play would be $x_1=\frac14+\frac12\varepsilon$, then $x_2=1-x_1$ and finally $x_3\in(x_1,x_2)$ does a coin flip to decide if it wants to steal more from $x_1$ or $x_2$, giving the other one the win.

---

**$n\in\mathbb N$ players case**

> Is it possible to solve this for general $n$ ?

I'm wondering if there is a way to find conclusions about the game in general, other than tackling individual $n$ cases.

Comment: Question about scoring: Suppose the points chosen by the $n$ players are $0\le x_1<x_2<\cdots < x_n \le 1$. Then would the scoring for player 1 would be $\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{x_1+x_2}{2}-x_1\right) = \dfrac{x_2-x_1}{4}$ and for player $n$ would be $\dfrac{1}{2}\left(x_n-\dfrac{x_{n-1}+x_n}{2}\right) = \dfrac{x_n-x_{n-1}}{4}$. And then for any $k=2, \ldots, n-1$, the score for player $k$ would be $\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{x_k+x_{k+1}}{2}-\dfrac{x_{k-1}+x_k}{2}\right) = \dfrac{x_{k+1}-x_{k-1}}{4}$?

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding the scoring for the edge points. I think the scoring for the player who played $x_1$ would be $\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{x_1+x_2}{2}+x_1\right) = \dfrac{3x_1+x_2}{4}$ and for the player who played $x_n$ it would be $1-\dfrac{x_{n-1}+3x_n}{4}$.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe  Why the extra $\frac12$ ? The scoring is based on dividing the segment. $-$Assuming $0\le x_1 \lt x_2 \lt x_3 \lt \dots \lt x_n \le 1$, the $x_k\in(x_{k-1},x_{k+1})$ owns $I_k=(\dfrac{x_{k-1}+x_{k}}{2},\dfrac{x_{k}+x_{k+1}}{2})$ hence its score would be $s_k=|I_k|=\dfrac{x_{k+1}-x_{k-1}}{2}$. The scoring for $x_1\in[0,x_2)$ would be $s_1 =   \frac12\left(x_1+x_2\right)$ because $x_1$ owns $[0,x_1]$ and $[x_1,\dfrac{x_1+x_2}{2})$.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I have a feeling that for large $n$ answer might depend on size of $\varepsilon$. Are you interested only in the answer in the limit case $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: @prosinac Yes the $\varepsilon$ is arbitrarily small but never $0$, so its size shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: Something I didn't prove, but this is the way I think about the game, it might help others if true. Claim: "Consider different game with no $\varepsilon$ restriction, but when you place a point on already existing point you have to declare if it is to the left or right to previous point. Scoring is the same, except if two points on the same spot share their score, whoever got there first is better." I am pretty confident this game is equivalent to yours and for me, it's easier to think about.